# Output file while inside initialize block

Tags: ruby

I have a class similar to below, we'll call it `TestClass`:

```
class TestClass

  def output_files
    a = ("a".."j").to_a

    f1 = File.open("test.txt", "w")
    f2 = File.open("test2.txt", "w")
    a.each do |l|
      f1.write("#{l}\n"
      f2.write("#{l}\n")
    end
    f1.close
    f2.close
  end
end
```

If I do this:

```
t = TestClass.new do
  output_files
end
```

I expect this to output two files, even though it will return an instance of `TestClass`. It doesn't output any files though. How can I output a file while inside of a block like this?

If I do:

```
t = TestClass.new
t.output_files
```

This does in fact output the files.

Comment: what did you mean? output the contents of those files ?

Comment: Output a file to the local file system. As such, the files aren't created.

Comment: The `new` method does not yield blocks like this. You will have to override `new` with a version that takes and handles the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) or [`BasicObject#instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec):

```
t = TestClass.new.instance_exec do
  output_files
  self
end
```

You can also write `TestClass#initialize` to get rid of some boilerplate:

```
class TestClass
  def initialize(&blk)
    blk && initialize_exec(&blk)
  end
end
# ...
t = TestClass.new do
  output_files
end
```